# Есть ли альтернатива opendir, readdir?

Tags: php

В общем такая проблема: на вдс не работает данный скрипт

---

```
define("H", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/');
$opdirbase=opendir(H.'system/functions');
while ($filebase=readdir($opdirbase))
{
if (eregi('\.php$',$filebase))
{
require_once(H.'system/functions/'.$filebase);
}
}
```

---

Можно ли чем-то заменить opendir, readdir? Или что нужно сделать чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d = dir('system/functions');

while (false !== ($filebase = $d->read())) {
    if ($filebase!== '.' || $filebase!== '..'){
        // чего-то делаем
    }
}

$d->close();
```

А вы вообще разбирались почему ваш вариант не работает? Ошибку какую-то выбивает? Может просто права на директорию надо установить подходящие?

---

**UPD**

Сделайте простую проверку и посмотрите, правильны ли все пути к файлам:

```
define("H", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/');

function get_files($path, $mask = '*'){
    $sdir = array();
        // получим все файлы из дирректории
        if (false !== ($files = scandir($path))){
            foreach ($files as $i => $entry){
                // если имя файла подходит под маску поика     
                if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && fnmatch($mask, $entry)){
                    $sdir[] = $path.'/'.$entry;
                }
            }
        }
    return ($sdir);
}

var_dump( get_files(H.'system/functions', '*.php') );
```

Comment: Вот ошибка в лог-файле - [06-Aug-2012 13:03:53] PHP Warning:  opendir(/home/vekto665/public_html/system/functions) [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/vekto665/public_html/portal/system/functions.php on line 3

И также перстала информация записываться в БД - $name=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])); - почему-то не обрабатывается.

Comment: Так у вас проблема не в скрипте, а в не правильных путях. 

> No such file or directory

Говорит о том, что по заданному вами пути, файл или директория не найдена. И скорее всего, что "ноги" проблемы растут отсюда:

    define("H", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/');

Напишите просто:

    define("H","http://vash_site.ru/");

Comment: Попробовал: [06-Aug-2012 15:21:58] PHP Warning:  opendir(http://site.ru/portal/system/functions) [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: failed to open dir: not implemented in /home/vekto665/public_html/portal/system/functions.php on line 4
[06-Aug-2012 15:21:58] PHP Warning:  readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource in /home/vekto665/public_html/portal/system/functions.php on line 5


Не работает.


Мне нужно сделать загрузку функций из папки. Каждая функция находится в отдельном файле.

Comment: > Мне нужно сделать загрузку функций из папки.

Вот тю ... А почему ж просто не подключить эти файлы?

    include('my_file.php');

Comment: Лучше require Подключить десяток файлов не проблема.
Только вот теперь другой вопрос: почему post-запросы не обрабатываются?



Может апач глючит?

Comment: А $_POST['name'] прилетает? Выведите её на экран перед тем, как что-то с ней делать. И посмотрите в моем ответе дополнение.

Comment: Можно еще по FTP соединяться. Для этого спец. функции есть.